# Hybrid vs Native mobile app sensors

Tags: performance, native, sensors, hybrid

The application we are planning to develop will make heavy use of some of the sensors of the device. More specifically the GPS sensor, the accelerometer and gyroscope.

We have to decide which is better to make one hybrid application for all platforms - Android/iOS/Windows or make separate native apps. We want sensor performance and also the main logic of the solution is contained in one single class which could be extracted as a C library and used across all platforms, is that a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

I your case I will go for native... but also you can use hybrid version just for the UI, so you do not have to design it for all platform. Using hybrid solution does not stop you from adding native libraries, you can use you custom library in Java Android for sensor for example...